# (Novice) Is there a way to skip executing part of the program based on a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried defining my own goto fuction (I know this is a bad idea, but the only idea I have had). Is there a better way to skip some lines of code based on a variable. This is the code I have at the moment

```
x = len(list)
#
ltr1 = list[0] 
ltr2 = list[1]  
ltr3 = list[2] 
ltr4 = list[3] 
ltr5 = list[4]
ltr6 = list[5] 
ltr7 = list[6] 
ltr8 = list[7] 
ltr9 = list[8] 
ltr10 = list[9] 
ltr11 = list[10] 
ltr12 = list[11] 
ltr13 = list[12]
#
```

In this instance I would want the program to only execute some of the lines between the hashes - i.e `if x = 5` I would only want it to execute up to the line `ltr5 = list|[4]`, skip the code after that that is inside the hashes and continue with the code after that.

Comment: why make all these variables? Just use your list directly with indexes? For example: instead of making `ltr1`, just use `list[0]`? (Also, don't name your list variable as `list`, that "hides" the builtin `list`)

Comment: agree with Paritosh, also, you can just use # at the beginning of the line to not execute the specific line

Comment: ok, thanks, tbh i am not too experienced with python, but i intend to have the variable ```x``` change based on input

Comment: That will be much easier to do if you don't use individual hard-coded variables e.g. given a list of items `data`, if you only want to process the first 5 items you can use `data[:5]` which creates a new list of only the first 5 items (or `itertools.islice(data, 5)` which does the same thing except lazily). If you have a bunch of local variables you can't really do that.

Comment: okay. is it possible to use ```data[:x]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make ltr1 as a list an the loop over list based on the variable x to fill values in ltr1

```
ltr1 = [None]*13
x = len(list)
for i in range(x):
    ltr1[i + 1] = list[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can already access the data using list[index], Why do you want to store that inside new variables. Even if you want to you should copy that inside some other list.

You can use if else conditions for that 
like

```
if x == 5:
     ltr1 = list[0] 
     ltr2 = list[1]  
     ltr3 = list[2] 
     ltr4 = list[3] 
     ltr5 = list[4]
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

Comment: isnt there a faster way to do this? i intend to  have x change based on user input, so using ```if```` statements would surely be a bit of a cumbersome way to do it.

Comment: What is the usecase to store list values in new vaariables? You can already access tha data using list[index].
You can use a for loop like `for x in list`

Comment: @theoddllama iterate on the list instead of hard-coding every case, then either put a conditional on the index in the list or use something like slicing or `itertools.islice` to limit the number of entries you process.

Answer (score -1):

look into `argparse` library [https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html]

then you could use a lot of if statements to execute a particular line

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')

# parse line number from terminal as arguments
parser.add_argument('i', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

# execute line number conditionally
if args.i == 0:
    print("first")
if args.i == 1:
    print("two")
```

#

```
python3 <filename.py> 0
```

this will print `first`

Comment: thanks, ive had a look around, it seems to be helpful, could you give a code example?